# No such file or directory for esp_adafruit_ssd1306

Tags: arduino

I'm working with Arduino now. I'm trying to `#include <ESP_Adafruit_SSD1306.h>` and this error code is showing up:

> G:\Kuliah\tna\arduino\sketch_jun11a\sketch_jun11a.ino:6:34: fatal error: ESP_Adafruit_SSD1306.h: No such file or directory
>
> `#include <ESP_Adafruit_SSD1306.h>`

I added the library using sketch-> include library -> manager library and searched for adafruit ssd1306.h

Answer (score 0):

This means that the IDE can't find that library, are you sure you already installed it correctly?